# XMPP Registration with Smack API returns bad-request - modify

Tags: xmpp, smack

I am trying to register a user using the Smack API (4.1.5) AccountManager class createAccount method. I get the following log and the request seems to always fail bad-request. How do I figure out whats wrong with the request?
I tried changing the username by removing domain and resource etc but still the same result. Could there be an issue with the length of the fields. 
I have also read about XEP0077 here http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0077.html
but could not figure out this issue.

```xml
D/SMACK: SENT (0):
<iq to='xmpp.jp' id='w50y8-3' type='get'>
  <query xmlns='jabber:iq:register'></query>
</iq>
D/SMACK: RECV (0):
<iq from='xmpp.jp' id='w50y8-3' type='result'>
  <query xmlns='jabber:iq:register'>
    <instructions>Choose a username and password to register with this server</instructions>
    <username></username>
    <password/>
  </query>
</iq>
D/SMACK: SENT (0): 
<iq to='xmpp.jp' id='w50y8-5' type='set'>
  <query xmlns='jabber:iq:register'>
    <username>test@xmpp.jp/SMACK</username>
    <password>test123</password>
  </query>
</iq>
D/SMACK: RECV (0):
<iq from='xmpp.jp' id='w50y8-5' type='error'>
  <query xmlns='jabber:iq:register'>
    <username>test@xmpp.jp/SMACK</username>
    <password>test123</password>
  </query>
  <error code='400' type='modify'>
    <bad-request xmlns='urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-stanzas'/>
  </error>
</iq>
W/System.err: org.jivesoftware.smack.XMPPException$XMPPErrorException: XMPPError: bad-request - modify
```

Can someone please help me understand how to diagnose such issues and how to figure out whats wrong with the above request?

Answer (score 0):

You need to determine the required account attributes via https://www.igniterealtime.org/builds/smack/docs/4.1.5/javadoc/org/jivesoftware/smackx/iqregister/AccountManager.html#getAccountAttributes() and provide these.

Comment: Thanks. According to http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0077.html#usecases-register. If the required information is missing then the server should send not-acceptable (406) response back. But I am getting 400. 
But I will still try as you have suggested and will get back with the result.

Comment: I added this line
    Set<String> requiredAttrs = accountManager.getAccountAttributes();
And this came back with username and password as required. I have already provided both fields.

Comment: In this case, you have to ask the server, i.e. look at the server's source, why it is returning bad-request.

Answer (score 0):

I was passing incorrect service name in XMPPTCPConnectionConfiguration.setServiceName() which caused packets drops in IQRouter as client is not authenticated yet. Hope this helps someone!!